# why declare constrexpr constructors for classes with non-trivial destructors (e.g. unique_ptr, std::variant)

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr, c++17

As far as I understand (at least for `c++14`), a destructor cannot be `constexpr` if it is not trivial (implicit generated or `=default`). What is the point of declaring `constexpr` constructors for structures with non-trivial destructors?

```
struct X {
  int a_;

  constexpr X(int a) : a_{a} {}

  // constexpr ~X(){}; // Error dtor cannot be marked constexpr
  // ~X(){}; // causes  error at y declaration: temporary of non-literal type ‘X’
             // in a constant expression .
};

template <int N> struct Y {};

int main() {
  Y<X{3}.a_> y; // OK only if the destructor is trivial
  (void)y;
}
// tested with c++14 g++-5.1.0 and clang++ 3.5.0
```

For instance `std::unique_ptr` has some [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) `constexpr` (default and `nullptr_t`), even though the destructor is obviously explicitly defined (sure it has no effects if the object is `nullptr`, but doesn't that mean that it still has an explicit-defined destructor in order to check if the object is in an empty state, and as I've seen, even an empty destructor doesn't allow an object to be used in a compile-constant expression)

Another example is the proposal for [std::variant](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4542.pdf): it has almost all the constructors `constexpr` although the destructor has the signature `~variant()` and it has to `call get<T_j> *this).T_j::~T_j() with j being index().`

What am I missing?

Comment: See also: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2976.html

Comment: You're missing the fact that C++ makes no bloody sense any more.

Comment: inb4 lol @ "any more"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [N3597](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3597.html) suggested `constexpr` destructors, but *"no compelling use cases are known"*. So a type that can be used in constant expressions needs to have a trivial dtor. OTOH, constant init is a use-case for types with constexpr ctors that cannot be used in a constant expression.

Comment: @dyp: It shouldn't be necessary to even think about any of this. (Notice I'm not necessarily saying it should or could be automated)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`constexpr` constructors can be used for constant initialization, which, as a form of static initialization, is guaranteed to happen before any dynamic initialization takes place.

For example, given a global `std::mutex`:

```
std::mutex mutex;
```

In a conforming implementation (read: not MSVC), constructors of other objects can safely lock and unlock `mutex`, because `std::mutex`'s constructor is `constexpr`.

Comment: Hasn't MS fixed that for VS2015? Also, http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2976.html

Comment: @dyp Not for `std::mutex`.

Comment: Would you happen to have a link where I can read more about that? MSDN says it's a `constexpr` constructor, so is *constant initialization* missing in VS2015 or is it something specific to `std::mutex`?

Comment: @dyp There seems to be two problems. One is specific to `std::mutex`, whose default constructor isn't `constexpr` in VS2015 - 4th bullet in the list in [this VC blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/02/constexpr-complete-for-vs-2015-rtm-c-11-compiler-c-17-stl.aspx). The other is that they are also not doing constant initialization properly - search for "DevDiv#1134662" in that blog post and the comments.

Comment: Thanks, [this page about `mutex::mutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921463%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) is misleading then...