# std::unique_ptr constexpr constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

As shown [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), `std::unique_ptr` has two `constexpr` constructors for null pointers:

```
constexpr unique_ptr();
constexpr unique_ptr( nullptr_t );
```

I have two questions for these two constructors:

1. Why do we need two? Can't we just declare one as:

   ```
   constexpr unique_ptr( nullptr_t = nullptr );
   ```
2. Is the `constexpr` really useful? I tried doing this in my code but it didn't compile (g++ 6.1.0, `-std=c++14`):

   ```
   constexpr std::unique_ptr<int> p;
   // error: the type 'const std::unique_ptr<int>' of constexpr variable 'p'
   // is not literal because 'std::unique_ptr<int>' has a non-trivial destructor
   ```

Comment: That links back to this same question

Comment: LOL copy/paste fail. But oldrinb's answer links to the one I meant to link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For (1), consider that it ensures that both the no-arg constructor `unique_ptr()` and null-pointer constructor `unique_ptr(nullptr_t)` have the same compile-time guarantees, i.e. both are `constexpr`. We can see the difference in §20.8.1.2:

```
constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;
explicit unique_ptr(pointer p) noexcept;
...
constexpr unique_ptr(nullptr_t) noexcept
: unique_ptr() { }
```

Why the two were not combined into a single constructor with a default value is likely historical contingency.

With regards to (2), why we should care about `constexpr` despite having a non-trivial destructor, consider [the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766445/591495):

> `constexpr` constructors can be used for constant initialization, which, as a form of static initialization, is guaranteed to happen before any dynamic initialization takes place.
>
> For example, given a global `std::mutex`:
>
> ```
> std::mutex mutex;
> ```
>
> In a conforming implementation (read: not MSVC), constructors of other objects can safely lock and unlock `mutex`, becuase `std::mutex`'s constructor is `constexpr`.

Answer (score 9):

As to Q1, the `nullptr_t` constructor was added later in [N2435](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2435.htm), well after the original proposal ([N1586](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1856.html)).

Adding a simple overload that can be specified in one line is much cleaner than trying to be clever, especially as [member.functions] already allows the implementation to use the "clever" version if they want.

Comment: So the current two ctors specified in the standard should be functionally equivalent to the one in my question, correct?